# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Sound Problem

Tags: 12.04, sound, lts

lost my sound by installing Realtek HD Audio Drivers Linux Version got no HDMI choice tried googling for various codes ended up on Dummy Output in Sound and got no sound controll anymore can anyone help me im new :(

Answer (score 0):

Go over [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)
.I hope this will be helpful.Do post if your problem is not solved.

Comment: so you mean to say you want me to download it and install again?

Comment: I was just making sure that you have downloaded the right package!

Comment: Installing Pulse Audio Volume Control ,gives the HDMI audio options, needed: From:https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/paman/